# Обособление деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь обособлять деепричастный оборот "открывая глаза"? Каждый
мой день рождения начинался с того, что(,) открывая глаза, я видела около кровати стул с лежащим на нем подарком, красиво упакованным и загадочным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: Каждый мой день рождения начинался с того, что, открывая глаза, я видела около кровати стул с лежащим на нем подарком, красиво упакованным и загадочным.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Обособление ка основная форма

Задумавшись, князь шёл по тропинке. Играя, в небе промелькнёт рассыпанная стая скворцов. Оглянувшись, Илья с весёлой улыбкой вскочил.К ней, лая, кинулись собаки. Татьяна, вспыхнув, задрожала.Григорий молчал, задумавшись. Верблюдов длинный ряд дорогой тянется, мелькая.

2) Нет обособления (исключение)

Деепричастия и нераспространенные деепричастные обороты не обособляются при наличии следующих признаков:а) обозначают признак действия и играют  роль обстоятельства образа действия в основном сообщении; б) можно заменить наречием-синонимом;  в) могут находиться в однородных отношениях с наречием; г) часто находятся в конце  предложения, являясь при этом центром высказывания;  д) обычно не обособляются деепричастия несовершенного вида.

Лошади шли не спеша. Царица молча сошла со ступеней. Не торопясь я спустился к оврагу. Князь шёл задумавшись. Что, сударь, плачете? Живите-ка смеясь. Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь. Илья Ильич не спеша сошёл вниз.    К дверям кабинета все подходили обыкновенно перешёптываясь и на цыпочках.

3) Парный вариант

На солнышке Полкан с Барбосом, лёжа, грелись.Но: После обеда ложились отдохнуть, но не засыпали, а разговаривали  лёжа.

Comment: А какой здесь случай? Разве это не деепричастие несовершенного вида?

Comment: Деепричастие не обособляется, когда утрачивает глагольность и приближается к наречию. "Открывая глаза" - чистое действие. Ср.: лежа, грелись = грелись, когда лежали. Разговаривали лежа = как?

Comment: Глаголы несовершенного вида чаще обособляются, но это не условие обособления. Вот, к примеру, два варианта обособленных деепричастий в конце предложения: "Григорий молчал, задумавшись. Верблюдов длинный ряд дорогой тянется, мелькая". Кажется, деепричастие идет после глагола, почему бы не приравнять его к наречию и не обособить? Почему бы не задать вопрос "как"? Здесь помочь может только структурная грамматика. Если не обособим деепричастия, то глагол не будет иметь тонического ударения, деепричастие станет центром высказывания, а это не входит в планы автора.

Comment: Тоническое ударение и планы автора становятся очевидны постфактум и не могут служить критерием постановки запятой. Критерий - глагольность при самодостаточном сказуемом и наречность при несамодостаточном. "При блеске внезапно сверкнувшей молнии он увидел, что стоит прижавшись к колонне". Возможны 2 варианта в зависимости от того, какой смысл у сказуемого: если герой до этого сидел, то теперь "стоит, прижавшись к колонне". Если важно, как именно стоит, то без запятой.

Comment: В отсутствие автора при первой правке текста проверяем самодостаточность сказуемого. "Молчал" и "дорогой тянется" - самодостаточные.

Comment: Как только автор написал свой текст, то тонические ударения в большинстве случав уже заданы его структурой (если, конечно, у нас с Вами одинаковые представления о тоническом ударении). Только в некоторых случаях возникает возможность двойного толкования, и тогда мы говорим об авторских решениях, например: "Я шел, улыбаясь, а он отвлекал Темных". Вообще (говоря), меня удивляет консерватизм людей, считающих, что они всё делают превосходно и ничего лучшего не может быть по определению. Можно, конечно, ломать голову над самодостаточностью, но появляются и  более простые и очевидные решения.

Comment: Ой, София, не работали вы с текстами малограмотных журналистов. Когда автор сам не знает, какое у него должно быть тоническое ударение, и даже вопроса не понимает, приходится ориентироваться на критерий из учебника - самодостаточность сказуемого. А вот на личности переходить необязательно. Какие вас там люди удивляют и какие характеристики вы мне приписываете, к деепричастным оборотам не относится.

Comment: Да я не про Вас, я про консерваторов - так, лирическое отступление, надо было скобочки поставить. Извините, если нечаянно Вас обидела.